# Как отформатировать и записать дату в БД?

Tags: php, база-данных

Дата после выбора в input имеет вид 31.12.2016, как мне записать её в бд, если там нужно чтобы она была в формате `Y-m-d` ?

```
$termin = $product['date_available']; //здесь я получаю дату в формате dd.mm.yyyy

$this->data['date_available'] = date("D-m-Y", strtotime($termin)); //сюда нужно передать дату в формате yyyy-mm-dd
```

Comment: почему `D`, а не `d` ? и формат даты в базе обычно гггг-мм-дд, т.е. `Y-m-d`

Comment: так мне посоветовали в ответе ниже

Comment: в ответ ниже тоже `D`, а не `d` - это выведет `2016-10-Sat`, а Вам нужно `2016-10-29`, т.е. `Y-m-d`

Comment: Переправил D на d, результат тот же. Дата была 29.10.2016 а в базу записалась 2029-10-20

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/582324/191745), у Вас неправильно вставляется дата, т.к. Вы задаете неправильный формат даты. поменяйте `D-m-Y`, на `Y-m-d`. т.е. Вы пытаетесь  вставить дату `29-10-2016`, а нужно `2016-10-29`.

Comment: и так и так не работает, сейчас попробую в запросе исправить как вы посоветовали

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47350/discussion-between-alex-and-abmin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1** - привести датe к формату до записи в базу данных.

```
$this->data['date_available'] = date("D-m-Y", strtotime($termin));
```

замените на

```
$this->data['date_available'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($termin));
```

**Вариант 2** - привести к нужному формату в запросе к бд:

```
STR_TO_DATE('29.10.2016','%d.%m.%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

`$date = "31.12.2016";`
`echo date("Y-m-D", strtotime($date));`

Вот так можно переформатировать дату

Comment: Я переправил вопрос используя ваш ответ, но так не работает. Дата была 29.10.2016 а в базу записалась 2029-10-20

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется для таки вещей лучше использовать средства самого MySQL

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('', STR_TO_DATE(  '31.12.2016',  '%d.%m.%Y' ))
```

Comment: ответы не смотрите совсем)

Comment: Ну пока писал свой и на всякий случай проверял его работоспособность в реальной БД, появился ваш :)